# Toggle jQuery div to open and close not working correctly

Tags: jquery

I am trying get a toggle working for a datatable filter. When creating the basic button, I can open and close the div using

```
<a data-toggle="collapse" href="#epdatatable_filter" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="epdatatable_filter" class="btn btn-labeled bg-primary">Filters </a>
```

My issue is when I add a reset button within the div and set the button to toggle it closed, it does a complete different style close and then will not reopen. I noticed how the first button can remove the display: none but the reset cannot.

Is there a way of getting this working or is there a more efficient way of doing it? The end result is to create a APPLY and RESET button within the div which both will close afterward.

My code: https://jsfiddle.net/martinhackett/Lru4npte/17/

```
                <div style="float: right"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#epdatatable_filter" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="epdatatable_filter" class="btn btn-labeled bg-primary">Filters </a></div>


                <div class="card collapse" id="epdatatable_filter">
                  <div class="card-header header-elements-inline">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Search</h5>
                  </div>

                  <div class="card-body">
                    <div class="row">
                      <div style="float: right"><a id="epdatatable_filter_reset" role="button" class="btn btn-labeled bg-primary">Reset filters </a></div>

                      <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <label for="searchbox"><b>Name:</b> </label>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                          <input class="form-control filter_reset" type="text" id="searchbox">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <label for="searchbox1"><b>Email:</b> </label>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                          <input class="form-control filter_reset" type="text" id="searchbox1">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <label for="searchbox"><b>Telephone:</b> </label>
                        <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                          <input class="form-control filter_reset" type="text" id="searchbox2">
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-3">
                        <p id="searchbox3"><label><b>Filter:</b></label><br></p>
                      </div>
                      <div class="col-xl-12">
                        <button id="filter_submit">Apply Filters</button>
                      </div>

                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>


<script>
$(document).ready(function () {


$('#epdatatable_filter_reset').click(function(){
    $('#epdatatable_filter').toggle();
})

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I edited your code it's pretty simple here's what you wanna do:

- remove `show` class from the div
- set `are-expanded="false"`
- remove display none
  here's an example: [Check Me](https://jsfiddle.net/syfzcdaw/)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the toggle on the element and data attributes for toggle aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="epdatatable_filter" like the other link and it will work.

```
            <div style="float: right"><a data-toggle="collapse" href="#epdatatable_filter" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="epdatatable_filter" class="btn btn-labeled bg-primary">Filters </a></div>


            <div class="card collapse" id="epdatatable_filter">
              <div class="card-header header-elements-inline">
                <h5 class="card-title">Search</h5>
              </div>

              <div class="card-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div style="float: right"><a id="epdatatable_filter_reset" role="button" class="btn btn-labeled bg-primary"  data-toggle="collapse" href="#epdatatable_filter" role="button" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="epdatatable_filter" >Reset filters </a></div>

                  <div class="col-xl-3">
                    <label for="searchbox"><b>Name:</b> </label>
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                      <input class="form-control filter_reset" type="text" id="searchbox">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-3">
                    <label for="searchbox1"><b>Email:</b> </label>
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                      <input class="form-control filter_reset" type="text" id="searchbox1">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-3">
                    <label for="searchbox"><b>Telephone:</b> </label>
                    <div style="padding-bottom: 10px">
                      <input class="form-control filter_reset" type="text" id="searchbox2">
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-3">
                    <p id="searchbox3"><label><b>Filter:</b></label><br></p>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-xl-12">
                    <button id="filter_submit">Apply Filters</button>
                  </div>

                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

remove this part

```
    $('#epdatatable_filter_reset').click(function(){
    $('#epdatatable_filter').toggle();
})
```

or use bootstrap methods

```
collapse('toggle')
```